# Can I write to a FileStream and then read from it WITHOUT waiting on the backing disk?

Tags: .net, performance, caching, memory, filestream

My application makes many rapid web service calls to its server.  Each call it serializes an object that it passes as an argument to the web service call.  Often that object serializes to something pretty small... say 5KB or less... in which case, I'd rather just serialize to a MemoryStream and then send the bytes from that MemoryStream.  But sometimes that object serializes to something pretty huge... say 50MB (50,000KB)... in which case, serializing to a MemoryStream would severely compromise the Large Object Heap... and so, would be better serialized to a FileStream.

It occurs to me that if a FileStream has a large enough buffer size, then I should be able to write to it, seek back to the beginning, then read from it, and never actually get out of the memory buffer... such that my thread should (theoretically) perform roughly the same speed as memory up to that buffer size.  True?

(Yes, I am going to do some measurements... but I could easily miss cases where it would behave differently... or related issues that could negate the results... things the collective intelligence here will often tell me.  Thanks!!)

Is there a reliable high-performance approach to having a file-backed memory stream that only uses the file if it needs to grow larger?  (I am hoping the answer is "Yeah, just use FileStream with buffer size set to the size of the memory stream you want.")

Comment: Can't you just serialize directly to the network stream?

Comment: Nick, I can't serialize directly to the network stream because if the serialized data ends up large I will need to send it in chunks (separate web service calls), otherwise the web service will end up timing out.  So, we typically limit one chunk to 5MB... though we allow our users to tune that, since some have slower networks than others.